# Adding types["node"] in tsconfig results in type definition error

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, visual-studio-code

I have a NodeJS project that has a type declaration file so I can add properties to the Request object:

**@types/express/index.d.ts:**

```
import { User } from "../../src/entity/user.entity";

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      user?: User;
    }
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "typeRoots": ["@types"],
  ...
}
```

So far, this works perfectly fine. However, when I want to add `types` or change `typeRoots` in my **tsconfig.json** to:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "@types"]
  "types": ["node"]
  ...
}
```

it suddenly does not work anymore and throws errors at me in VSCode:

`Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.ts(2339)`

Any idea what causes this? Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In ambient declaration files, you *cannot* have either `import` or `export`, because that would make them of type 'module'.

That means to use the typings defined in the declaration file, you would have to import or reference it in every file you need to use it in.

However, without the import or export, it's a script type file, and works as an ambient declaration file.

So how do we get around this:

```
import { User } from "../../src/entity/user.entity";

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      user?: User;
    }
  }
}
```

Well, it's a little known feature that you can use `import` like a function in a type:

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      user?: import("../../src/entity/user.entity").User;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I only change the d.ts file to what you suggested, it returns the same error while trying to access the user property. When I then also modify the `tsconfig.json` to what I desire, the `declare global` also red underlines with the error `Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.ts(2669)`

Comment: That’s odd, because it should already be an ambient module declaration. Are there any imports or exports in the file?

Comment: No. However, I found my error 1 second ago: I also defined an `include` as key in my `tsconfig.json` containing `["./src/**/*.ts"]`, adding `"./@types/**/*.ts"` did the trick.

Comment: Nice! Glad you could solve it.

Comment: Ok, I was wrong, only the red lines disappeared in VSCode. When I want to run the server the error still occurs in the terminal.